# JAVASCRIPT - Why isn't this object changed?

Tags: javascript, object

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
  theObject = {make: "Ford", model: "Focus", year: 2006};  
}  
var mycar = {make: "Honda", model: "Accord", year: 1998};  
var x = mycar.make;     // returns Honda  
myFunc(mycar);  
var y = mycar.make;     // still returns Honda
```

Why doesn't myFunc change the mycar object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is already answered, just to make it even clearer:

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
      theObject = {make: "Ford", model: "Focus", year: 2006};  
}
```

is something similar (forget the syntax, get the message) to:

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
      theObject = new TheObject("Ford","Focus",2006);  
}
```

in other words, the parameter is referenced but you are changing that reference by constructing a new object.

Note: Since Java syntax is so popular I thought of using a JAVA-like syntax in order to explain, with didactic purposes, that you're creating a whole new instance. "TheObject" would be the name of the class.

Comment: why 'TheObject' as new? what does it do?

Comment: `};` should be `);` by the way

Answer (score 9):

When you do `theObject = { ... }` within `myFunc`, you are creating a new object and assigning its reference to the local variable `theObject`. This does not change the original object.

To modify the contents of the original object, you need to directly modify its properties like this:

```
theObject.make = 'Ford';
theObject.model = 'Focus';
theObject.year = 2006;
```

Comment: I don't get this. I thought that `theObject` in `myFunc` was a reference to the object that was passed in to `myFunc`, and not a local variable?

Comment: It is, but he is assigning a new object to the local variable, not modifying the passed in object's properties.

Comment: @Tola Odejayi: `theObject` itself isn't a reference to `mycar`, it *holds* a reference to `mycar`. You can change `mycar` through `theObject`, but if you assign another object to `theObject`, it now *holds* the new reference.

Comment: Ah... got it. So `theObject` in `myFunc` and `myCar` outside `myFunc` both point to the same object at the start of `myFunc`, but the moment we do the `new`, `theObject` now points to a **different** object.

Comment: @Tola Odejayi: Exactly, object references are really just pointers in disguise.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is modifying the local reference not the original reference when making the change you supplied. This post on SO should help:

[Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-is-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Is this not correct? It sounds the same as the other answers.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I guess mentioning another SO post with some great examples and explanation are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
      theObject = {make: "Ford", model: "Focus", year: 2006};  
    }
```

Here you are reassigning your variable to a new object.  The original is left unchanged, because parameter does not link to the variable holding the object.

to:

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
  theObject.make = "Ford";
}
```

This changes the object's properties you passed in.