# What does this javascript code mean?

Tags: javascript, object

```
function myFunc(theObject) {  
      theObject = new TheObject("Ford","Focus",2006);  
}
```

Why is `new TheObject()` used instead of something like `new Object()`? I don't understand.

Comment: How is `new Object()` different from `new TheObject()` other than its name??

Comment: The `}` on `("Ford","Focus",2006}` is probably a typo? :)

Comment: Object and TheObject are two different classes -- two different types of data.  What if I asked you how is Orange different from Computer other than its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the code you posted to work, somewhere else on the same page has to be something like the following:

```
var TheObject = function(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
```

Then, your posted code will create a new object with properties defined by the TheObject function. (In the above example, you could access the make of your new object by referencing `theObject.make`.)

Comment: That explains it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :) Also, are you learning JS with a tutorial? It doesn't seem like they are using the best examples. If I were you I would pick up a copy of JavaScript: The Good Parts, by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: this example came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557185/javascript-why-isnt-this-object-changed/4557522#4557522

Answer (score 4):

There's a `function TheObject(...)` "class" somewhere this is creating that occurs before this in your included code, *that's* what it's creating.

Answer (score 3):

TheObject is a user defined object.

Answer (score 2):

Here, TheObject is the type of object (class) which "theObject" is.  The function with the same name as the type is called a constructor.  Calling it constructs a new object of that type. (e.g. for a TheObject type, new TheObject() creates a new object of the type TheObject)

Think of it this way:  The function below makes myAuto a new Car object (of type "Car"):

```
function myNewFunc(myAuto) {
  myAuto = new Car("Audi","TT",2001);
}
```

(It's possible the "Object" vs "TheObject" vs "theObject" terminology is confusing you.  Where are you getting this sample code?)

Comment: How is this 'TheObject' different from other objects?

Comment: As thismax said above, the TheObject datatype was defined somewhere else in the class.  Now that I see where this came from (another SO question), I can see why it was confusing, as ivo_es did not provide the definition with his example.